# Can't pass html to lxml from mechanize

Tags: html, parsing, mechanize, lxml

I'm a total newb, so please forgive me for what is probably really easy.  I am using mechanize to login into a pw protected site - which works just fine and returns the html of the post-login page.  I am trying to pass that html into lxml to parse some table results.  This is not working and instead of parsing with xpath the print txt1 returns all of the html.

This is the code I have post the successful login:

```
# Get html
html = br.response().read()

# LXML
doc = lxml.html.parse(html).getroot()

txt1 = doc.xpath('/html/body/div/div[2]/div[3]/div[1]/table[1]/tbody/tr[1]/th//text()')

print txt1
```

I got the XPATH from inspector on chrome for the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Install `cssselect` from PyPI.

```
dom = lxml.html.fromstring(html)
tables = dom.cssselect('table')
print tables[0].text_content()
```